# Ошибка и съедание памяти

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть программа, которая записывает действия мыши (макрос) и там есть возможность вставлять С#. У меня между командами вставляется 3 C# кода, то есть примерно это выглядит так:

```
C# 
КЛИК ПО КООРДИНАТАМ (CLICK X X)
ВСТАВИТЬ В ПОЛЕ ИЗ БУФЕРА ОБМЕНА (PASTE)
ЖДЁМ 3 СЕК (DELAY 3000)
C# 
КЛИК ПО КООРДИНАТАМ (CLICK X X)
ВСТАВИТЬ В ПОЛЕ ИЗ БУФЕРА ОБМЕНА (PASTE)
ЖДЁМ 3 СЕК (DELAY 3000)
C#
КЛИК ПО КООРДИНАТАМ (CLICK X X)
ВСТАВИТЬ В ПОЛЕ ИЗ БУФЕРА ОБМЕНА (PASTE)
```

Иногда всё работает стабильно без ошибок, иногда выдаёт ошибку:

> Текущий поток должен быть задан как поток однопоточного контейнера
>   (STA), чтобы вызовы OLE стали возможны. Проверьте, что ваша функция
>   Main помечена атрибутом STAThreadAttribute.

А иногда Windows пишет, что недостаточно памяти. Скорее всего я что-то недопонимаю и что-то работает нелогично. Я около недели пытался найти решение проблемы, но ничего не помогло. Последнее, что я сделал, это добавил `[STAThread]`, но и это тоже не помогло. Поэтому пришёл спрашивать советы у Вас. **Сильно не ругайте меня, с C# у меня первый опыт.**

Прикрепляю 3 вставки кода:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
 [STAThread]
 public static void Main() {
  try {
   using(var file_track_title = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AMData\track_title.txt")) {
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(file_track_title.ReadLine());
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
 }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
 [STAThread]
 public static void Main() {
  try {
   using(var file_login = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AMData\login.txt")) {
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(file_login.ReadLine());
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
 }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public class Program {
 [STAThread]
 public static void Main() {
  try {
   using(var file_password = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\AMData\password.txt")) {
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(file_password.ReadLine());
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: У вас же код в этих трех примерах одинаковый, меняется только названия файлов!? Порождающий процесс должен быть `[STAThread]`, а не дочерние, т.е. "Есть программа, которая записывает действия мыши (макрос) и там есть возможность вставлять С#." - эта программа и должна быть `[STAThread]`

Comment: @Bulson, да, меняется только название файлов и переменных. Программа видимо не `[STAThread]`, раз ошибка есть.

Comment: Попробуйте этот [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17762059).

Comment: @Bulson, если не сложно, можете показать как это сделать в моём коде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = @"D:\test.txt";

    System.Threading.Thread thread = new Thread(() => SetToClipboard(file));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();

}

private static void SetToClipboard(string pathToFile)
{
    try
    {
        string line = String.Empty;
        //все же поток лучше закрыть перед тем как дергать др.сущность типа Clipboard
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(pathToFile))
        {
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(line);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Отлично, проверю и напишу :)

Comment: Проблема решена, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @ModaL, вот и хорошо, пожалуйста.